# Installing an older version of Adobe Flash player

Tags: flash, adobe

My application requires Adobe Flash player to install. So if you are trying to install application and you have not installed Adobe Flash player yet, it automatically suggests you install Flash player. So by default this application needs version 10.2 so it tries to install it, but adobe blocks it, because it says that I am trying to install an old version of flash player, so how can I avoid this blocking, so I don't need to install the newest version of Flash player each time? How can I automatically install required version of Flash player?

Comment: Hi guys, I figured out it by myself, if you go here
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\SafeVersions
and than delete for example "10.0" variable you will be able to install oldest version of flash player 10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out it by myself, if you go here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\SafeVersions and than delete for example "10.0" variable you will be able to install oldest version of flash player 10.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use the latest version of Flash Player as a lot of security fixes and patches are made. Do you want to test the behavior of your application in a previous version or simply fed up of having to install an update from time to time? :)

If you want to install older versions of Flash Player, check [this](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html) link.